# Implement IExtensibleDataObject by default on Proxy

Tags: java, c#, wcf, proxy

Whiel generating proxy class by using SVCUTIL.exe or By Adding service reference from VS, it inherits the IExtensibleDataObject to the data contract classes by default.

**WCF data contract**

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**WCF Servcie**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public Employee GetEmployeeById(Employee employee)
        {
            return employee;
        }
    }
```

Proxy Class generated by adding service reference from VS and Employee composite class in client side inherits IExtensibleDataObject interface by default even though i haven;'t implement this in service end.

**Client side Employee Class**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Employee", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    public partial class Employee : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
        private string IdField;


        [global::System.ComponentModel.BrowsableAttribute(false)]
        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData {
            get {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Id {
            get {
                return this.IdField;
            }
            set {
                if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.IdField, value) != true)) {
                    this.IdField = value;
                    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the question is, While generating proxy from some other client (For ex: Java), will they implement IExtensibleDataObject interface by default?

Answer (score 0):

No, because `IExtensibleDataObject` is an interface from .Net Framework.
The service will run even without it. It provides a way to store extra data, that is not present in the contract:

> The IExtensibleDataObject interface provides a single property that
>   sets or returns a structure used to store data that is external to a
>   data contract. The extra data is stored in an instance of the
>   ExtensionDataObject class and accessed through the ExtensionData
>   property. In a roundtrip operation where data is received, processed,
>   and sent back, the extra data is sent back to the original sender
>   intact. This is useful to store data received from future versions of
>   the contract. If you do not implement the interface, any extra data is
>   ignored and discarded during a roundtrip operation.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iextensibledataobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: If I implement IExtensibleDataObject  in service data contract, i couldn't able to find any information about this in WSDL. So if non.net client (Java) generates proxy, then how data loss going to be avoid during round trip? Will they have any separate interface as like .net framework has (IExtensibleDataObject ) ?

Comment: I don't know if Java or any other languages has an equivalent implementation, anyway, IExtensibleDataObject is useful to store data received from future versions of the contract, if you implement the correct version of your contract, you will not have any problem with no .net clients.